# mobicent sip servlet with jboss as 7 in cloud

Tags: jain-sip

I Have developed javaee solution for mobicent sip servlet. I need to share the application with client for a test purpose. how I can upload mobicent in a cloud? or is it possible to share my local pc with static ip mobicent url (jboss service) over internet?

Answer (score 1):

We just created an AMI on the Amazon Marketplace, see https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00G9G94JW/ref=sp_mpg_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-4
so you can just spin off a new instance and deploy your application there to share it with your customer. User Guide is here http://www.telestax.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy it to Amazon EC2 and share the IP with your client.